# Problem with javascript with this particular animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, eclipse, animation

So, i was working on the animation of a football field in 3D with css. this is what i have
[image] and this should be what i would like to have [image: what i would like to have]

my codes are the following,they are all taken from this repository, i've only added the tags body,head and html.

html: https://codepen.io/paulnoble/pen/PwOxOY.html 
css:https://codepen.io/paulnoble/pen/PwOxOY.css 
and this is the js: https://codepen.io/paulnoble/pen/PwOxOY.js inside my project, i've already added velocity.min.js e jquery.min.js. 
the full repository is at https://codepen.io/paulnoble/details/PwOxOY

and i'm having this error here.

```
campo.js:428 Uncaught TypeError: $teamListHome.velocity is not a function <br>
    at Object.preLoad (campo.js:428) <br>
    at init (campo.js:660) <br>
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (campo.js:667) <br>
    at i (jquery-1.12.1.min.js:2) <br>
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.1.min.js:2) <br>
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.1.min.js:2) <br>
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery-1.12.1.min.js:2) <br>
```

how can i solve this error? Admitting it would be the only one. 
this my html

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://codepen.io/paulnoble/pen/PwOxOY.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://codepen.io/paulnoble/pen/PwOxOY.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Formazione</title>
<%@include file="header.html"%>
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <div class="static">
        <h1 class="js-heading">FOOTBALL LEAGUE</h1>
        <p class="js-subheading">Experimental team line-up and football field using CSS 3D transforms.<br><span style="font-size: 11px">Currently buggy in Chrome, will fix soon :)</span></p>
        <div class="js-switcher switcher">
            <a href="#" class="js-switch disabled switch-btn">HOME</a><a href="#" class="js-switch switch-btn">AWAY</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="js-stage stage texture">
        <div class="js-world world">
            <div class="team js-team">
                <!-- Team cards / icons goes here -->
            </div>
            <div class="terrain js-terrain">
                <div class="field field--alt"></div>
                <div class="field ground">
                    <div class="field__texture field__texture--gradient"></div>
                    <div class="field__texture field__texture--gradient-b"></div>
                    <div class="field__texture field__texture--grass"></div>
                    <div class="field__line field__line--goal"></div>
                    <div class="field__line field__line--goal field__line--goal--far"></div>
                    <div class="field__line field__line--outline"></div>
                    <div class="field__line field__line--penalty"></div>
                    <div class="field__line field__line--penalty-arc"></div>
                    <div class="field__line field__line--penalty-arc field__line--penalty-arc--far"></div>
                    <div class="field__line field__line--mid"></div>
                    <div class="field__line field__line--circle"></div>
                    <div class="field__line field__line--penalty field__line--penalty--far"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="field__side field__side--front"></div>
                <div class="field__side field__side--left"></div>
                <div class="field__side field__side--right"></div>
                <div class="field__side field__side--back"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="loading js-loading">PLEASE WAIT...</div>
    </div>
    </main>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **just have** to add jquery scripts before velocity scripts, or it won't work.

**Before:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://codepen.io/paulnoble/pen/PwOxOY.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://codepen.io/paulnoble/pen/PwOxOY.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**After:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js"></script>    
<link href="https://codepen.io/paulnoble/pen/PwOxOY.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://codepen.io/paulnoble/pen/PwOxOY.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```